# Error Could not deserialize ATN with version (expected 4) when loading pytorch_lightning

Tags: python, antlr, antlr4, pytorch-lightning

When trying to import pytorch_lightning

```
import pytorch_lightning as pl
```

I get the `Exception: Could not deserialize ATN with version  (expected 4)`.
I'm using pytorch 2.0.0+cu118, pytorch-lightning 2.08, Python 3.9.12 runtime, anltr4 runtime 4.11.1 on Windows 11 machine. What can I do to resolve this? I've never even heard of ANTLR until today so if the solution requires working with ANTLR please share step-by-step instructions or link, not 'regenerate the parser'. Thanks.

I tried reinstalling different versions of the libraries mentioned in the problem description.

Comment: Maybe this helps - https://stackoverflow.com/questions/76308886/could-not-deserialize-atn-with-version-expected-4-while-using-python-age-drive